# missing afl-gcc even after installing af++

Tags: fuzzing

Program abort: afl-gcc is not available on your platform
Location: mode_final_checkout(), src/afl-cc.c:1201

I tried to install g++ and reinstall afl++ but nothing seems to help

tried on a ubuntu vm on Mac m2, any suggestion would be appreciated.